# Como configurar o path (URL) de uma aplicação Java web de maneira correta para não ter erros 404 (Not Found) quando o projeto está em produção?

Tags: java, xml, heroku, jersey

Eu tenho um projeto Java web na qual uso o Jersey framework. Quando faço deploy no meu localhost (uso Tomcat 9) tudo funciona, quando levo pra o Heroku a app também funciona. Porém, quando faço requisição para um serviço, por exemplo, no meu localhost. Uso a url "http://localhost:8080/myapp.service/rest/pessoa" para salvar os dados da entidade `Pessoa`. Já quando faço requisição para o app pela url "https://my-app.herokuapp.com/myapp.service/rest/pessoa" me retorna erro 404. Eu acredito que no processo de deploy com o "heroku-maven-plugin", o url está sendo outra.

Uso esses plugins no pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.13</version>
</plugin>
```

Meu web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
    <display-name>myapp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>myapp.app.rest</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Este é o log de quando faço deploy com o comando mvn clean heroku:deploy-war:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                                                                                                         
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                          
[INFO] ---------------------< doctorplus:doctorplus.app >----------------------                                                                                         
[INFO] Building doctorplus.app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                                                                                                           
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------                                                                                             
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                                            
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\meunome\eclipse-workspace\doctorplus.app\target                                                                                              
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] >>> heroku-maven-plugin:2.0.13:deploy-war (default-cli) > package @ doctorplus.app >>>                                                                           
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                                
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!                                                       
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\meunome\eclipse-workspace\doctorplus.app\src\main\resources                                                       
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                                   
[INFO] No sources to compile                                                                                                                                            
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                        
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!                                                       
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\meunome\eclipse-workspace\doctorplus.app\src\test\resources                                                       
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                           
[INFO] No sources to compile                                                                                                                                            
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                                        
[INFO] No tests to run.                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.1:war (default-war) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                                                
[INFO] Packaging webapp                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO] Assembling webapp [doctorplus.app] in [C:\Users\meunome\eclipse-workspace\doctorplus.app\target\doctorplus.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]                                 
[INFO] Processing war project                                                                                                                                           
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\meunome\eclipse-workspace\doctorplus.app\WebContent]                                                                        
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1650 msecs]                                                                                                                                 
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\meunome\eclipse-workspace\doctorplus.app\target\doctorplus.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war                                                       
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] <<< heroku-maven-plugin:2.0.13:deploy-war (default-cli) < package @ doctorplus.app <<<                                                                           
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO]                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO] --- heroku-maven-plugin:2.0.13:deploy-war (default-cli) @ doctorplus.app ---                                                                                     
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.5.47.2:jar                                                                                               
[INFO] Copying webapp-runner-8.5.47.2.jar to C:\Users\meunome\eclipse-workspace\doctorplus.app\target\dependency\webapp-runner.jar                                    
[INFO] -----> Packaging application...                                                                                                                                  
[INFO]        - app: doctorplus-app                                                                                                                                     
[INFO]        - including: target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar                                                                                                          
[INFO]        - including: target/doctorplus.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war                                                                                                     
[INFO] -----> Creating build...                                                                                                                                         
[INFO]        - file: target/heroku/build.tgz                                                                                                                           
[INFO]        - size: 32MB                                                                                                                                              
[INFO] -----> Uploading build...                                                                                                                                        
[INFO]        - success                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO] -----> Deploying...                                                                                                                                              
[INFO] remote:                                                                                                                                                          
[INFO] remote: -----> heroku-maven-plugin app detected                                                                                                                  
[INFO] remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done                                                                                                                        
[INFO] remote: -----> Discovering process types                                                                                                                         
[INFO] remote:        Procfile declares types -> web                                                                                                                    
[INFO] remote:                                                                                                                                                          
[INFO] remote: -----> Compressing...                                                                                                                                    
[INFO] remote:        Done: 83.5M                                                                                                                                       
[INFO] remote: -----> Launching...                                                                                                                                      
[INFO] remote:        Released v17                                                                                                                                      
[INFO] remote:        https://doctorplus-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku                                                                                          
[INFO] remote:                                                                                                                                                          
[INFO] -----> Done                                                                                                                                                      
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                         
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS                                                                                                                                                    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                         
[INFO] Total time:  05:34 min                                                                                                                                           
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-10T12:20:42-03:00                                                                                                                           
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Se tiver como, posta log do Heroku ao fazer o deploy

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o log. Aparentemente tudo ok!

Comment: Posta o log do console do Heroku, fica mais fácil de identificar o problema

Comment: Olá, Você configurou o seu contexto? Uma vez que esta sendo utilizado o TomCat faça a configuração do contexto conforme a [documentação da apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) A definição de contexto em projetos WAR não é definida na especificação Java EE, por isso cada servidor tem a sua mais informações [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664059/how-do-you-specify-the-root-context-in-your-web-app-tags-in-web-xml/664089#664089) Abraços!